# Python module not getting installed on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, cryptography

I have a Django application that, when trying to deploy to Heroku, complains about not finding the 'Crypto' module:

```
...
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
remote: Running release command...
remote:
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py", line 177, in import_from_string
remote:     return import_string(val)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 17, in import_string
remote:     module = import_module(module_path)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
remote:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:   File "/app/oda_project/users/authentication.py", line 14, in <module>
remote:     from Crypto.Cipher import AES
remote: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
```

Works fine locally on my machine, and I have added the module to requirements.txt. Even tried installing with the Heroku CLI.

Has anyone successfully used python cryptography on Heroku, and how? I am using the module to encrypt/decrypt strings.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
This is my requirements.txt:

```
requests
Crypto
boto
app==0.0.1
asgiref==3.2.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.0.2
djangorestframework==3.11.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
python-dotenv==0.10.5
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

I have it at the root of my project. Doing `pip list` in the Heroku Console I get:
[image]

Comment: can you show your directory structure and the contents of requirements.txt?

Comment: @Ken4scholars I've added some extra info. The heroku deployments worked fine until I added the Crypto package

Comment: Try adding the version for crypto in the requirements file. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely using a library on your local computer that is not part of the Python standard library.

You need to add your requirements to your requirements.txt file or your Pipfile. See the relevant [Heroku documentation on requirements in Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip).

As an aside, if you're using Pycrypto, you main consider some alternatives, as it's [no longer maintained](https://github.com/pycrypto/pycrypto/issues/285).